# How to center UICollectionViewCell that was focused?

Tags: tvos, apple-tv

What I want to achieve is very simple: each time user focuses a collection view cell, I want to make the focused cell horizontally centered. It seems like my current approach doesn't work at all.

```
    func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didUpdateFocusInContext context: UICollectionViewFocusUpdateContext, withAnimationCoordinator coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
        guard collectionView === self.categoryCollectionView else {
            return
        }
        guard let indexPath = context.nextFocusedIndexPath else {
            return
        }

        collectionView.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: .CenteredHorizontally, animated: true)
    }
```

What is odd is that collection view ignores any attempt to scroll anywhere. For testing purposes, I changed index path to the last item's index path in collection view, but it works only when collection view appears for the first time.

Answer (score 8):

The trick is to make sure you have set UICollectionView scrollEnabled = false.

```
override func didUpdateFocusInContext(context: UIFocusUpdateContext, 
  withAnimationCoordinator coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
    if let focusedView = context.nextFocusedView as? UITableViewCell {
      collectionView.scrollEnabled = false
      let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathForCell(focusedView)!
      collectionView.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: .CenteredHorizontally, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me, the focus get selected outside of the screen and the collection view doesn't scroll.

Comment: This trick somewhat works, but the animation looks totally different from the normal interaction between the focus engine and a scrollview, so I'm going to have to figure something else out.

Answer (score 0):

I remember reading somewhere in [AirBnB's guide to the Focus Engine](http://nerds.airbnb.com/tvos-focus-engine/) that they covered this somewhat. Their code ([on GitHub](https://gist.github.com/bachand/364eb3add94b0de12318#file-masteringfocusexample5-swift)) is for the UIButton class, but hopefully you can draw abstracts for CollectionView from that.

Hope it helps you find the solution!